# Как спрятать сообщение "New names" в консоли?

Tags: r

При использовании функции `bind_cols` получаю в console сообщение о том, что некоторые столбцы переименованы.

> Как отключить вывод в консоль New names: ... ?

Пробовал отключить warning message -
`options(warn = -1)`

Но результата это не дало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>А Вы пробовали использовать функцию [suppressWarnings](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/warning)? Она подавляет все предупреждения, включая `New names`, поэтому, если другие предупреждения Вам не критичны, можете использовать её как решение данной проблемы.</strike>

UPD: Не та функция, почему-то взял другую, схожую с верной, функцию >.<
Попробуйте теперь функцию [suppressMessages](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/message) — она стерёт все сообщения, в числе которых, разумеется, и `New names`.

Comment: Если обвернуть выражение функцией suppressWarnings - предупреждение так же выводиться в консоль

Пример
x <- tibble( d=1 )
z <- x
f <- suppressWarnings(bind_cols(x,z))

Comment: Оказывается, я перепутал функции =/ Ответ изменил, надеюсь, что теперь это поможет

Comment: Да, помогло! Большое спасибо !